# How do I do things concurrently with JQuery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have these lines:

```
$( "#textEmail" ).addClass('gc-input-subscribe-invalid', 1000, "linear" );
$( "#emailWarning" ).show();
```

These execute one after the other.

Ideally, I'd like them both to be executed together over the course of 1000ms.

How can I do that?

Comment: By "concurrently" you mean [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)? (How can a class even be added "concurrently"? Referring to the documentation will show there is not such a nonsensical version of `addClass`.)

Comment: @user2864740 - I wouldn't call it "nonsensical".  Actually, it's quite powerful and useful!  [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/addClass/) extends `.addClass()` to accept additional parameters and animate the differences between classes.

Comment: som @gilly3 is there a way to run those two simultaneously over the course of the 1000ms ?

Comment: @RM1970 - I have the same question as user2864740... How do you "show" something over the course of 1000ms?  If you mean fade it in, see the link in the top comment.  Maybe you want to slide it in, or have it enlarge from 0px, or...

Comment: the new class that i'm adding has red border. I'd like to add the red border to the input field as a fade-in. also at the same time, I'd like to fade in the warning text #emailWarning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by [using jQuery UI `addClass()`](https://jqueryui.com/addClass/). To run them concurrently, put them in a function and call the function.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/7s2dsd2o/)

### Javascript

```
function showTheStuf() {
    $("#textEmail").addClass('gc-input-subscribe-invalid', 1000);
    $("#emailWarning").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

### CSS

```
.gc-input-subscribe {
    border:solid 2px #FFF; /* Your background/previous border color. */
}
.gc-input-subscribe-invalid {
    border:solid 2px red;
}
#emailWarning {
    display:none;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="emailWarning">Warning!</div>
</div>
<input id="textEmail" class="gc-input-subscribe" value="ex@ample.com">
<button onclick="showTheStuf()">Click me!</button>
```